# OpenGL: PyCharm quit unexpectedly on Mac

Tags: macos, opengl, pyqt, pycharm

I'm trying to run a project on Mac OS X that works on windows. The project is using the OpenGL and PyQt libraries. There seems to be a problem trying to use the OpenGL library.

I downloaded a OpenGL demo of a helix that works.

```
print("OpenGL: " + str(glGetString(GL_VERSION)))
```

returns OpenGL: b'2.1 NVIDIA-10.0.51 310.90.10.05b12'

When I try to run the other project, PyCharm quits unexpectedly and I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/CS 410/Agile-Development-Project-master2/package/ui/widgets/gamewidget.py", line 177, in initializeGL
    glPrimitiveRestartIndex(self.restart)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 402, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
  File "errorchecker.pyx", line 53, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError (src/errorchecker.c:1218)
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glPrimitiveRestartIndex,
    cArguments = (4294967295,)
)
```

[Picture of Mac Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HZyT.png)

[Project Link](https://github.com/2017-SP-CS410/Agile-Development-Project)

mainwindow.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtOpenGL
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import QMainWindow, QStackedWidget
from package.ui.widgets import GameWidget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        glformat = QtOpenGL.QGLFormat()
        glformat.setVersion(3, 1)
        glformat.setProfile(QtOpenGL.QGLFormat.CoreProfile)

        self.setWindowTitle('Game name here')
        #self.stacked_widget = QStackedWidget(GameWidget())
        self.setCentralWidget(GameWidget(glformat))
```

**init** in gamewidget.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, n=10, **kwargs):
```

setting version to 3.2:
glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns a 3.3 context

new error (python still quits unexpectedly):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daniel/WSCU/Spring 2017/CS 410/Agile-Development-Project-mastercurrent/package/ui/widgets/gamewidget.py", line 183, in initializeGL
    self.initializeCube()
  File "/Users/daniel/WSCU/Spring 2017/CS 410/Agile-Development-Project-mastercurrent/package/ui/widgets/gamewidget.py", line 142, in initializeCube
    program = self.loadShaders()
  File "/Users/daniel/WSCU/Spring 2017/CS 410/Agile-Development-Project-mastercurrent/package/ui/widgets/gamewidget.py", line 227, in loadShaders
    raise RuntimeError(glGetShaderInfoLog(fs))
RuntimeError: b"ERROR: 0:6: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragColor'\n"
```

EDIT:

```
def initializeTimer(self):
    self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
    self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)
    self.timer = QBasicTimer()
    self.timer.start(1200, self)
    self.step = 100
    self.pbar.setValue(self.step)
    self.btn = QPushButton("Time is: " + str(int(self.step * 1.2)), self)
    self.btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: black; color: red;")
    self.btn.move(500, 10)
    self.show()


def timerEvent(self, e):
    if self.step <= 0:
        self.timer.stop()
        return
    self.step -= 1
    self.score += 1
    # print(self.score)
    self.btn.setText("Time is: " + str(int(self.step * 1.2)))
    self.scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + str(int(self.score)))
    self.pbar.setValue(self.step)
    self.pbar.setVisible(True)
    print(self.btn.text())
    print(self.pbar.text())


def makeScoreLabel(self):
    self.scoreLabel = QPushButton("Score: " + str(int(self.score)), self)
    self.scoreLabel.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: red;")
    self.scoreLabel.move(200, 10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a 2.1 context and `glPrimitiveRestartIndex()` is a 3.1 (core) function.

To request a 3.1 context, create a `QGLFormat()` and specify the version.

```
glformat = QtOpenGL.QGLFormat()
glformat.setVersion(3, 1)
glformat.setProfile(QtOpenGL.QGLFormat.CoreProfile)
```

Then pass it to your `GLWidget` as you create it `QGLWidget(glformat)`.

---

So in relation to your project. Since `GameWidget` extends `QGLWidget` that means that you should pass `glformat` to `GameWidget` in `mainwindow.py`.

```
self.setCentralWidget(GameWidget(glformat))
```

Note your `__init__` in `GameWidget`. Since `n` comes before `*args` that means `b` ends up being `format`, so you need to rearrange it like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, n=10, **kwargs)
```

---

Your problem now is actually your fragment shader.

> 0(5) : error C7533: global variable gl_FragColor is deprecated after version 120

You set your version to `330` this means that `gl_FragColor` is deprecated. Instead you have to specify your own color output.

```
#version 330

out vec4 outColor;

in vec3 fcolor;

void main()
{
   outColor = vec4(fcolor, 1.0);
}
```

*You still need to pass `glformat` to `QGLWidget`.*

---

**Edit:**

If you want to add say a label, then instead of this:

```
self.widget = GameWidget()
self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
```

Then you need to do this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel

self.label = QLabel()
self.label.setText("Hello World")

self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

self.widget = QWidget()
self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)

self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
```

The problem with that is of course that now we have a new `QWidget` and not the `GameWidget` (`QGLWidget`). The problem here is that you can't just easily add other widgets to a `QGLWidget`. That's why in relation to OpenGL people usually have custom GUI or a separate window for all the controls, labels and whatnot.

Comment: I'm confused as to where to put that. I added a link above to the project I'm working on. I tried it put it mainwindow.py and add it to the GameWidget() on the last line, line 11, but I didn't have any luck. Is this the wrong place?

Comment: I added your code, but I'm still getting the same exact error. See my edit for the changes I made. Did I make glformat in the wrong place?

Comment: Are you still getting the exact same error? Does `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` still return the same as well?

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting the same error. glGetString(GL_VERSION) still returns a 2.1 context.

Comment: When I try to change the version to 3.2, the context changes to 3.3 but I get a new error and python still quits unexpectedly.

Comment: Yes! Sorry for not getting back to you. Thank you so much for all your help. So I've been working on the project and put labels in the window, but none of them will show up on mac. The identical code works perfectly on windows, though. I don't get any error messages and the two print statements work as expected. Any idea why this is happening? Am I creating the widgets in an unorthodox way?

Comment: Take a look at my edit. You could probably call it *unorthodox* if you will. For future reference consider asking a new question to get the attention of more people.

Comment: Any idea why the current labels won't work on mac, but work fine on windows?